# CentOS7にMySQLがインストールできない

Tags: mysql, centos

Dockerで構築したCentOS7にMySQLをインストールしようとしましたが、
公開鍵の有効期限切れ？でインストールができない状況です。

実行したコマンド

```
yum localinstall http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
```

```
yum install -y mysql-community-server
```

```
# 実行結果抜粋
Public key for mysql-community-libs-5.7.42-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed


 Failing package is: mysql-community-libs-5.7.42-1.el7.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

対応として、以下２つを試してみましたが、結果は変わらずインストールできない状況です。
１.公開鍵の更新

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

2.キャッシュのクリア

```
yum clean all
```

どなたか対応策をご教示ください。

Comment: 5.7 は古いバージョンで、最新版は 8.0 になります。5.7 を選択しているのは理由がありますか？

Answer (score 0):

同じく Docker 環境で現象が再現しましたが、エラーメッセージで検索すると以下の記事がヒットします。

[GPGキーの関係でmysqlがインストールできない時の対処法](https://qiita.com/yuyanstart/items/e8a6f1d2fd7cbf1cfd59)

> ##### 原因
>
> GPGキーには有効期限が設定されており、期限が切れてしまうとGPGキーとしての役割を果たさなくなってしまいます。
>
> ##### 対策
>
> ```bash
> rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
> ```

リポジトリのトップを直接開いてみると現在も `RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022` が最新のようなので、これを上記手順でインポート後に再度 `yum` を実行したところ、`mysql-community-server` がインストールできました。

https://repo.mysql.com/

```
[FILE] RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql                 04-Nov-2021 10:51     2k  
[FILE] RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022            17-Jan-2022 10:22     3k
```